# Get rank of user by his name

Tags: php, sql, database

```
$query = "SELECT  uo.*, 
                 (
                   SELECT  COUNT(*)
                   FROM    Score ui
                   WHERE   (ui.score) >= (uo.score)
                 ) AS rank
          FROM    Score uo
          WHERE   name = '$politestring';";
```

My db is `idkw0t` and DB name is `idkw0t`. I have one table in it - `Users`. The `Users` table has 4 columns - `ID`, `Name`, `Score`, `Cash`.

How do I make the SQL query get the rank of a particular User by his name.
Like if there are 3 names - Joe[500 score], Tom[10 score] and John[50 score].
When I ask for the rank of Tom - it should echo by saying tom is in 3rd rank. When I ask Joe's rank, it should echo by saying Joe is in 1st.

My DB:

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Do you mean User or Score table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff my DB - http://prntscr.com/di5mjg

Comment: @DevilRooter your paste bin code is missing single quotes around `$politestring`. Php doesn't know to do that for you unless you use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a somewhat different method:

```
select count(*)
from score s
where s.score >= (select s2.score from score s2 where s2.name = $name);
```

Note:  This probably returns expected results if there are ties.  The above is based on your query.  You probably intend:

```
select 1 + count(*)
from score s
where s.score > (select s2.score from score s2 where s2.name = $name);
```

The above are examples of how the query should be written.  If you are calling this from an application, be sure to use parameterized queries.

Comment: whats mistake ?

Comment: Use mysqli_ and always use parameters for values in the query when you can.

Comment: can you help me in re-writing the code ? i dont get any result when I put username and fetch it